# How to parse a json file into a JsonArray object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net

I need to parse a json file to a JsonArray object in C#.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "LAkshan",
    "last_name": "Parcell",
   
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Lakshan",
    "last_name": "Clement",
   
  }
]
```

Json file's contains are like that. I need to get that data into a JsonArray object, not to specific object that created by me. When I try to do it like this

```
JsonArray list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonArray>(File.ReadAllText(JsonFilePath));
```

It throws this error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: Do you want to use the Newtonsoft.Json APIs or the System.Text.Json APIs? Pick one.

Comment: Basically, if you're happy using Newtonsoft.Json, deserialize into `JArray` instead of `JsonArray`.

Comment: @sweeper Ok I need to get a System JsonArray object by that file. So is there any method to do that using System.Text.Json API?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I need specifically a System JsonArray because it is needed to parse to another package (Fast report data souce) by JsonArray.

Comment: @PasinduLakshan you've mixed up different libraries. `JsonConvert` is a JSON.NET class while `JsonArray` is a System.Text.Json class. Use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` if you want to use System.Text.Json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this if you want to use JsonArray

```
JsonArray list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonArray>(File.ReadAllText(JsonFilePath),
        new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            AllowTrailingCommas = true,
        });
```

Comment: His json contains trailing commas so you need to add the corresponding option, otherwise this will throw an exception